# How to typeset a small black square as a binary operator?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

This is my first post on this SE so I apologize if my formatting is bad.

Essentially I am trying to reproduce the small black symbol from the following definition in Allen Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*:

[image]

([This book can also be accessed from his website for free](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), and this particular image is from page 26.)

I am trying to figure out how to typeset the small black square between the f and the g(s).  I tried the following in my preamble

```
\renewcommand{\bullet}{\tiny$\blacksquare$}
```

but the square bullet produced looks jarring and does not look like a binary operator, i.e. it is not centered and does not have equal spacing between f and g(s).

Would any of you have any suggestions on how to make this particular symbol?

Comment: This is actually not a square but just the shape of `\cdot` from the Lucida family used in the picture ([code](https://termbin.com/ow7q), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJaAy.png)).  Lucida is a commercial font, you can purchase it from [TUG](https://tug.org/store/lucida/index.html).

Comment: Ah, ok!  Thank you @HenriMenke!  That is very helpful information.  For now I think I will just have to settle for the "normal" \cdot to represent this operation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually not a square but just the shape of `\cdot` from the Lucida family used in the picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lucidabr}
\begin{document}
$f \cdot g$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Lucida is a commercial font, you can purchase it from [TUG](https://tug.org/store/lucida/index.html).

---

You could also go ahead and fake the symbol using a `\rule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\bullet{%
  \mathbin{\mskip1mu
    \mathchoice
      {\squarebullet{.25ex}{.25ex}}%
      {\squarebullet{.25ex}{.25ex}}%
      {\squarebullet{.18ex}{.18ex}}%
      {\squarebullet{.15ex}{.15ex}}
    \mskip1mu}
}
\newcommand\squarebullet[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{#1}{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
$f \cdot g_{f \cdot g_{f \cdot g}}$

$f \bullet g_{f \bullet g_{f \bullet g}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This symbol exists in the `mathabx` font package. Here is a way to use this symbol without having to load the package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}%
{<-6> mathb5 %
 <6-7> mathb6
 <7-8> mathb7 %
 <8-9> mathb8 %
 <9-10> mathb9 %
 <10-12> mathb10 %
 <12-> mathb12 }%
 {}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqbullet}{\mathbin}{mathb}{"0D}

\begin{document}

\[ f \sqbullet g\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Decide for the size of the black dot, here it is twice the size of (the bounding box of) a period, with a small sidebearing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pp}{}% check it's not defined
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pp}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\pp@\relax}}
\newcommand\pp@[2]{%
  \mspace{0.5mu}%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\sbox\z@{$#1.$}\rule{2\ht\z@}{2\ht\z@}}}%
  \mspace{0.5mu}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$f\pp g$

$\scriptstyle f\pp g$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the exact size of the black square as in the picture of the OP. I have made this with a new command `\bsq`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\bsq}{{\mkern 5mu}\blacksquare{\mkern 9mu}}

\begin{document}
\[f\raisebox{1pt}{\scaleto{\bsq}{2pt}} g(s)=
\begin{cases}
f(2s) &\\
g(2s-1)&
\end{cases}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This glyph is available in several packages as `\smblksquare`, including `unicode-math` (which I recommend), `stix` and `stix2`.  Its Unicode codepoint is ▪ (U+25AA).  Just define an operator with spacing `\mathbin`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\csquare{\mathbin{\smblksquare}}

\begin{document}
\( f \csquare g \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample]

There are several similar symbols, such as `\vysmblksquare` for a smaller version (⬝) or `\mdlblksquare` for a larger one (◼).  For example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX }
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}[Scale = 1.0]
\setmathfont[StylisticSet = 2]{STIX Two Math}

\newcommand\csquare{\mathbin{\vysmblksquare}}

\begin{document}
\( f \csquare g \)
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two font sample]

If you want to use a math font that doesn’t have this symbol, or has an ugly one, you can substitute the square from any other font of your choice with, e.g. `\setmathfont[range=\smblksquare]{Latin Modern Math}`.

If this is actually the `\cdot` symbol from Lucida, you could instead define `\csquare` by wrapping a `\mbox` inside `\mathbin`, or with `\DeclareMathSymbol`.

Answer (score 1):

To create a small blacksquare, I used the \atop command. This is used to show two terms vertically both of which are on top of the line eg. ${x \atop y}$. The idea is to ignore the lower term and then apply a subscript as in $_{x \atop}$ and this 'brings down' the upper term to the line level in a smaller size. Applying this to a blacksquare we get a small blacksquare:

$a(x-x_1)(x-x_2) = ax^2+bx+c \; {}_{\blacksquare \atop}$

ps. \; creates a space in math environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Sometimes I'm really astonished by the types of “solutions” people come up with in LaTeX.